# Why the output of this code is false? please answer me

Tags: javascript, typeof

```js
let number = 5;

console.log(typeof number !== "number")
```

---

I do not understand why a variable with a number type is equal to a string

Comment: You're getting its type, which is `"number"`.

Comment: `typeof number` returns `'number'` so `'number' === 'number'` returns `true` and `'number' !== 'number'` returns `false`.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused by the order of operations. Your code is the equivalent of `(typeof number) !== "number"`, not `typeof (number !== "number")`

Comment: Please do not say things like 'please help me' - just ask your question and people will help you if they can.

Answer (score 1):

because the type of number (in this case 5) is "number".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand why a variable with a number type is equal to a string

It's not the *variable* that is equal to a string, instead **it is the *type* that is (equal to) a string!**

The *type* of the variable `5` is `"number"` (as determined by `typeof number`) and `"number"` is a string.